# Wordpress, alternative single post template

Tags: single, plugins

For a project of mine I need to define an alternative template for single posts. To be more specific I need each post to be displayed as usual when the website is browsed but I need to create different single pages reachable from different URL to create a sort of a mini-website for each post.

(I'm actually using the WooCommerce plugin and what I need to do is to create a mini-website for each product. This needs to be something "outside" from the main website, with a complete different graphic template and is going to be reachable through a QR-code).

Hope it makes a bit of sense. Thanks for your advices and/or suggestions. Angelo

Answer (score 1):

You could set a url parameter to change the display so that the URL could be the same, then have your QR code do a pass-through to the desired page. Without knowing how the QR codes are setup and such, I can't offer much more on high-level implementation than that. The way to switch the templates would be as follows:

```
if( get_query_var( 'from_qr' ) == true )
    get_template_part( 'qr', 'single' );
else
    get_template_part( 'loop', 'single' );
```

You may want to use `$_GET` instead of `get_query_var()`, and you can structure that differently (I like `get_template_part()` because it makes the code easier to read and enhances my focus on SoC), but that's the general idea.